# How to use the GridView AutoGenerateDeletebutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to develop an asp.net app using c#. I created an GridView table by the following

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
                EnableViewState="False" OnRowDeleting="DeleteRowButton_Click">
        </asp:GridView>
```

But I do not know how to use the auto generated delete button in my c# code.

I search online, they always provide my code as

```
protected void DeleteRowButton_Click(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    var PN = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["Part_Number"];
    string PN = pn.ToString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XMLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    // Create the command object
    con.Open();
    string str = "DELETE * FROM XML WHERE ([Part_Numbber] = " + PN + ")";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Button1_Click(sender, e);
    con.Close();
}
```

Thank you very much for anyone can tell me how to do it

Comment: What's the error in your IDE?

Comment: It doesn't exist the upper function(calling)@ThanosMarkou

Comment: [e.RowIndex]  not available @ThanosMarkou

Comment: Please include the definition of the event handler

Comment: In what event handler do you put this line of code?

Comment: @JurijsKastanovs Could you please give me some example?

Comment: @rex You should define your comma-separated DataKeys in the gridview definition. E.g. DataKeyNames="Id" in the asp:GridView tag. This will make a DataKey named "Id" available, which is filled from the bound datasource (so make sure you have corresponding column in the datasource)

Comment: @JurijsKastanovs Thank you, I am trying it now. come back to you later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Delete any record from you should have any unique or Primary key. If you want to delete record using field "Part_Numbber" then this field data-type should be of either int or bigint in Database Table. Then Now put the following code to Delete.

```
protected void DeleteRowButton_Click(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int Part_Numbber= Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);       
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM XML WHERE Part_Numbber=" + Part_Numbber+ "", con);
    con.Open();
    int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Record deleted successfully";
    }
    con.Close();
    FillGrid();
}
```

How this may help you.

Comment: Sorry bro, I am not able to do it

Comment: .@rex kindly do it if you are able.