# Not able to access the ID while deleting the row from GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using a `Gridview` containing an ID. I want to write a `Row_deleting` event in which I access the ID from my .aspx page, but I am not getting it.

How can I do that?

Here is my Gridview Code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" 
    runat="server" CssClass="gridLink" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Serial_key") %>' 
    CommandName="Delete">
    <b>Delete</b>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Is that all of your code?

Answer (score 0):

first in your gridview set AutoGenerateDeletebutton=true then use this link
[How to use the GridView AutoGenerateDeletebutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905567/how-to-use-the-gridview-autogeneratedeletebutton)

```
protected void DeleteRowButton_Click(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

var PN = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["Part_Number"];// this is how you get the right row to delete e.rowindex is used to do this
string PN = pn.ToString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XMLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
// Create the command object
con.Open();
string str = "DELETE * FROM XML WHERE ([Part_Numbber] = " + PN + ")";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Button1_Click(sender, e);
con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Deleting any record from your database you need unique or Primary key column. If you want to delete record using column "Serial_key" . Then  put the following code to Delete.

```
<ItemTemplate> 
<asp:Label ID="lblSerial_key" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Serial_key") %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="deleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"  /></ItemTemplate>
```

Now you can use the lblSerial_key to delete a row

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string Serial_key = string.Empty;
        Label lblId = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("lblSerial_key");
        Serial_key = lblId.Text.ToString();
        string selectSQL = "delete from tablename where id='" + Serial_key + "'";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        // Create the command object
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL , con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```